# After raising IEnumerable.OrderBy(), the source list was not sorted，why?

Tags: ienumerable

1.First I defined an extension method for the IEnumerable.Add() like the code below

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value, Func<T, TKey> orderBy)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
            return null;

        if (enumerable is IList<T>)
        {
            var list = enumerable as IList<T>;
            if (!enumerable.Contains(value))
            {
                list.Add(value);
                enumerable = enumerable.OrderBy(orderBy);
            }
        }
    }
```

2.Then,I raised the extension method  like this to sort the itemlist according to the "Date" property when a new item was added to the list:

```
   itemList.Add(item, o => o.Date);
```

3.After all,it appears that the "itemList" was not sorted.

4.I followed the extension method and found that "enumerable" was a new instance after "enumerable = enumerable.OrderBy(orderBy)" and it was sorted,but the "list" was not.

5.Then I tried to cast the sorted enumerable to list like  "list=enumerable.ToList()",both of them("enumerable" and "list") were sorted.

6.After that ,when the call stack went back to the "itemList.Add(item, o => o.Date);",the "itemList" was not sorted at all!!!

Anyone can give me some advices?Thanks a looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the reference to enumerable is being passed by value rather than by reference. See [Jon Skeet's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) about passing parameters by value or reference for more information about what that means. In short, C# passes a copy of the parameter's reference so assigning a new value to parameter does not change the reference of the object that was passed in. To pass a parameter by reference you specify the `ref` keyword, but I don't think that will work with an extension method. If you're dead set on making this work I would suggest inserting the items into your List in sorted order, probably requiring that T implement IComparable.

**Update:**

First off, see the Skeet's article it's really quite informative and I will probably only be half as clear as he is. Second, when you pass an object as a parameter to a method you are passing a *copy* of the reference. This means you can still access members of the object but, the same way that a value type is passed by copy, if you modify the reference (ie assign it a new value) you wont modify the original reference. Specifying `ref` means that you are passing a reference to the reference and changing the reference (assigning a value to it) will affect the original object.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Do you mean that the "enumerable" was passed as a "Value" not a "Ref"?But I was taught that all the class types are  "Ref" type...Could you please give me more information?The link above can't be opened...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have got the point. Method(T t) and Method(ref T t) are different. In the first one,we can change t.Property but not t itself,when I create a new instance to t,the original source will not change.In another one,all the changes including Property or New instance will affect the original source.Thanks again!It's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Neither OrderBy or ToList will affect the source list. When you did this: `list=enumerable.ToList()` you changed your variable to point to a whole new list instance.

It appears to me that this method does too much. I would keep adding and sorting as separate operations. The fact that this extends IEnumerable but silently does nothing if the target is not an IList is a code smell.

Comment: Thank you very much!The extension method was defined for sorting when a new item was added,but it seems not work well...